# Reading \Seen, \Unseen flags using imaplib in Python

Tags: python, email, imaplib

Is it possible to read e-mail flags Seen, Unseen and restore them as the were before reading e-mail using imaplib in Python?
I couldn't find yet any information regarding reading these flags but there is plenty of examples setting Seen, Unseen etc. flags. I would appreciate if somebody would guide me to the right direction.

Comment: Yes, using `FETCH <mgs number> (FLAGS)` and `STORE <mgs number> +FLAGS (\Deleted)`. Read [rfc3501](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501.html)

Comment: And use FETCH.PEEK to avoid changing the flags to begin with.

Comment: Thank you +rfc3501 and +Max for helping me out in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

A big thanks goes to @stovfl and @Max in comments. I  successfully made my program work using `imap_conn.fetch(uid, '(BODY.PEEK[HEADER])')`. On the other side if somebody needs read-only access they can use `imap_conn.select('Inbox', readonly=True)`